# Returning the full contents of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
   function monkeyCount(n) {

     for (i=1; i<=n; ++i){
       let monkeyArray=[i];

       return monkeyArray[i];
     }    
   }
```

Another rookie question lol. I need to return the values of an entire array using the return statement and not the console.log. If I pass a number such as 5 to the function I need to return 1,2,3,4,5 your help much appreciated:0)

Comment: May I suggest you start using a debugger, and step through the code (once you solve the syntax errors). It will save you from asking us to be your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to append values to the array not reassign the array at every iteration of the loop. Try this:

```
const monkeyArray = [];
for(let i = 1; i<= n; i++){
monkeyArray.push(i);
}
return monkeyArray;
```

There are also many ways to do this such as with the lodash library where you can just call _.range(1, 6) to get an array from [1,6)

Comment: Cheers mate thats it rookie error but I suppose we all have to learn from out mistakes lol. Have a great evening mate and thanks for your help:0) Kind regards Jon

Comment: No problem. Happens to the best of us (which I can't say I'm party of). When you can, accepting the answer would be appreciated, but I understand there's time limits on those things.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, you just have try this on browser console.

```
function monkeyCount(n) {
    let monkeyArray = [];
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
       monkeyArray[i-1] = i;
    }
    return monkeyArray.join(',');
}
```